# Bitmap image from RecyclerView to Activity and from activity to Fragment

Tags: java, php, android, image, android-studio

I have a problem with image recovery. I do not know how to send from the `recyclerViewAdapter` to an `activity` and from the `activity` send the image to a `fragment`. With text or numeric data there is no problem, the problem is with the Bitmap data.

**I recover the data from phpmysql:**

```
if($consulta){

    if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $result["nombre"]=$reg['nombre'];
        $result["color"]=$reg['color'];
        $result["texto1"]=$reg['texto1'];
        $result["texto2"]=$reg['texto2'];
        $result["texto3"]=$reg['texto3'];
        $result["texto4"]=$reg['texto4'];
        $result["precio"]=$reg['precio'];
        $result["ancho"]=$reg['ancho'];
        $result["largo"]=$reg['largo'];
        $result["informacion"]=$reg['informacion'];
        $result["imagen"]=base64_encode($reg['foto']);
        $json['datos'][]=$reg;
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

**recovered the data from PHP in Android:**

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Conexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ListaArticulosPOJO miLista=null;

    JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");


    try{
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            miLista= new ListaArticulosPOJO();
            JSONObject jsonObject=null;
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            miLista.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
            miLista.setColor(jsonObject.optString("color"));
            miLista.setTexto1(jsonObject.optString("texto1"));
            miLista.setTexto2(jsonObject.optString("texto2"));
            miLista.setTexto3(jsonObject.optString("texto3"));
            miLista.setTexto4(jsonObject.optString("texto4"));
            miLista.setPrecio(jsonObject.optDouble("precio"));
            miLista.setAncho(jsonObject.optDouble("ancho"));
            miLista.setLargo(jsonObject.optDouble("largo"));
            miLista.setGrueso(jsonObject.optDouble("grueso"));
            miLista.setInformacion(jsonObject.optString("informacion"));
            miLista.setDatos(jsonObject.optString("fotoArticulo"));


            list.add(miLista);

            recuperaActivity=miLista.getNombre().toString();
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    RecyclerViewListaArticulosAdapter adapter=new RecyclerViewListaArticulosAdapter(list,getContext());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




}
```

**I store the data in an Intent within the RecyclerView:**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.id.setText(mDatos.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.color.setText(mDatos.get(position).getColor());



    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,ArticulosActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle= new Bundle();

            intent.putExtra("nombre",mDatos.get(position).getNombre());
            intent.putExtra("color",mDatos.get(position).getColor());
            intent.putExtra("texto1",mDatos.get(position).getTexto1());
            intent.putExtra("texto2",mDatos.get(position).getTexto2());
            intent.putExtra("texto3",mDatos.get(position).getTexto3());
            intent.putExtra("texto4",mDatos.get(position).getTexto4());
            intent.putExtra("precio",mDatos.get(position).getPrecio());
            intent.putExtra("ancho",mDatos.get(position).getAncho());
            intent.putExtra("largo",mDatos.get(position).getLargo());
            intent.putExtra("grueso",mDatos.get(position).getGrueso());
            //intent.putExtra("foto",mDatos.get(position).getFotoArticulo());

            intent.putExtra("informacion",mDatos.get(position).getInformacion());                intent.putExtra("foto",mDatos.get(position).getFotoArticulo());


            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}
```

**I recover the data in the activity:**

```
static String nombre;
static String color;
static String texto1;
static String texto2;
static String texto3;
static String texto4;
static double precio;
static double ancho;
static double largo;
static double grueso;
static String fotoArticulo;
static String informacion;
static ImageView imageView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_articulos);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_activity_articulos);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Intent intent=getIntent();
    nombre=intent.getExtras().getString("nombre");
    color=intent.getExtras().getString("color");
    texto4=intent.getExtras().getString("texto4");
    ancho=intent.getExtras().getDouble("ancho");
    largo=intent.getExtras().getDouble("largo");
    grueso=intent.getExtras().getDouble("grueso");
    precio=intent.getExtras().getDouble("precio");
    informacion=intent.getExtras().getString("informacion");
    fotoArticulo=intent.getExtras().getString("foto");

    //imageView=intent.getExtras().("foto");




    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fmLista1= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fmLista1.beginTransaction().replace((R.id.txt_base_articulos_izquierda),new ArticulosListaFragment()).commit();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fmLista2= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fmLista2.beginTransaction().replace((R.id.txt_base_articulos_derecha),new ArticulosDatosFragment()).commit();
}
```

**I call the data from the fragment and I show them:**

```
public ArticulosDatosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulos_datos, container, false);
    articulosActivity =new ArticulosActivity();


    radioGroup=(RadioGroup)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_radio_group);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId==R.id.txt_radio_eh){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"EH Pulsado ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(checkedId==R.id.txt_radio_gh){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"GH Pulsado ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    *imageView=(ImageView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_imagen_articulo);
    //imageView.setImageBitmap(articulosActivity.fotoArticulo);*

    informacion=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_articulo_informacion);
    informacion.setText(articulosActivity.informacion);

    texto1=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_text1);
    texto1.setText(articulosActivity.nombre);

    texto2=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_text2);
    texto2.setText(articulosActivity.color);

    texto3=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_text3);
    texto3.setText(articulosActivity.largo+" x "+articulosActivity.ancho+" x "+articulosActivity.grueso);

    texto4=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_text4);
    texto4.setText(articulosActivity.texto4);

    m2=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_precio_metro);
    m2.setText(articulosActivity.precio+"");


    bedarf=(EditText)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_cliente_metro);
    boton=(Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_boton_kalkulation);
    boxPrecio=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_precio_box);
    boxTotal=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_metros_total);
    menge=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_metros_total);
    summe=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_precio_total);


    return vista;
}
```

How to recover the Bitmap type image in the same way that I recover the other data. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you can pass image path and load image using glide.

Comment: Did you check answer?Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

What I get from your question is that you want to load your image which you got in base64 through json, So I'd answer for that.

Since you received the base64 as String, suppose it is enryptedImageString.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromEncodedString(String enryptedImageString) {
        if (enryptedImageString != null && !enryptedImageString.equals("")) {

            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(enryptedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodeBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            return decodeBitmap;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

This method will return Bitmap of your base64 string image.

Now your Fragment may have this:

```
imageView=(ImageView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_imagen_articulo);
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromEncodedString(articulosActivity.fotoArticulo));
```

Check for null condition of that method before.
Also I don't encourage creating Object of Activity instead you should try to use getActivity() if fragment attached properly.

You should avoid complete image transfer since in some case image could be quite large and rather pass the url by hosting it if possible.
And use Glide or Picasso library to show in imageview directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image path and load it as given by @Android Team or else u can convert that bitmap to byte array and then pass it to the intent via intent.putExtra and retrive the same.

you can try bitmap conversion with this  code:

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
bmp.recycle();
```